# cant display subset of list items using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of 5 calendar tiles across the top of my page. Each tile contains an unordered list with unequal amount of li tags as each day has differing numbers of events. I display only 5 events in each tile, and if there are more than 5 an li tag with an a tag within it to click on to show the next 5 li items. A tile renders as follows;

```
<div id="day1">
        <span id="lblDay1" class="calendartilelabel">10/9/2013</span>
        <hr class="calendartileline" />
        <ul id="FeaturedContent_day1List" class="calendartile">
    <li class='eventitem'>10:30 DOE U.S. Gasoline </li>
    <li class='eventitem'>10:30 DOE U.S. Distillat</li>
    <li class='eventitem'>10:30 DOE U.S. Crude Oil</li>
    <li class='eventitem'>10:30 DOE Cushing OK Cru</li>
    <li class='eventitem'>10:30 DOE U.S. Refinery </li>
    <li class='next'><a href='#'>Next--></a></li>
    <li class='eventitem'>Nov Corn Options Expiration</li>
    <li class='eventitem'>Nov Wheat Options Expiration</li>
    <li class='eventitem'>Nov Soybeans Options Expiration</li>
            <li class='eventitem'>Nov Sugar Options Expiration</li>
    <li class='eventitem'>Nov Cocoa Options Expiration</li>
            <li class='next'><a href='#'>Next--></a><a href='#'>Prev--></a></li>
    <li class='eventitem'>Nov Coffee Options Expiration</li>
    <li class='next'><a href='#'>Prev--></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I use this jquery to display 6 list items on each tile, 5 events and the click tag

```
 function showCalendarTiles() {
            $("ul.calendartile").each(function () {
                $("li:gt(5)", this).hide();
            });               
        }
```

How do I remove the 5 displayed items on a tag click event and display the next x number of items?

Comment: not similar since i need to change the list items based on which was clicked, next or previous, therefore the code must track what IS next and what WAS previous, preferably by index

Comment: If you keep track of the current index, then you just have to add or subtract a fixed number from that value to switch to previous/next – where’s the problem with that?

Comment: therein lies the problem, I have been trying to figure out how to get the count of items in the cliked ul, but nothing i try works and Im relatively new to jquery and dont know how to get the index of the clicked tag

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: i can get the index now of the list but i cannot get the length, this should work but doesnt   alert($(this).parents("li").length());

Comment: Log `$(this).parents("li")` to console to see what you are _actually_ selecting there …

Comment: $("ul.calendartile > li > a").on("click", function (event) {
                console.log($(this).parents("li"));  logs nothing to the console

Comment: alert($(this).parent().parent().children().length); is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that slice is the best method in jquery 2.0 and higher to achieve the result I am looking for as show below. (Thanks to CBroe)

```
 var priorIndex = 0;
 var numberOfItemsToDisplay = 22;

$("ul.updownsymbols > li > a").on("click", function () {
            var currentIndex = $(this).parent().index();
            var liTags = $(this).parent().parent().children();
            if ($(this).text() == "Next-->") {
                liTags.slice(0, currentIndex + 1).hide();
                liTags.slice(currentIndex + 1, currentIndex + (numberOfItemsToDisplay + 1)).show();
                priorIndex = currentIndex;
            } else if ($(this).text().match('<--Prev'))  {
                liTags.slice(priorIndex + 1, currentIndex + 1).hide();
                liTags.slice(priorIndex - (numberOfItemsToDisplay - 1), priorIndex + 1).show();
                priorIndex = priorIndex - numberOfItemsToDisplay;
            } else {
                $("#lblChartSymbol").text($(this).text());

                //make ajax call to get the chart data
            }
        });
```